# How to store data in my database from a user Input using MySQL in flask app. I am getting an Error

Tags: python, mysql, flask

Source code is as following:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
from MySQLdb import cursors

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = Sorry, can't show it.
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = Sorry, can't show it.

mysql = MySQL(app)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        userdetail = request.form
        username = userdetail['username']
        password = userdetail['user_password']
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO userinfo(username, user_password) VALUES(%s, %s),(username, user_password)")
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cur.close()
        return 'SUCCESS'
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is my code and I am here trying to get data from user and storing it in my Database but I am getting an ERROR:

```
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s, %s),(username, user_password)' at line 1")
```

It is actually showing the error in this particular line:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO userinfo(username, user_password) VALUES(%s, %s),(username, user_password)")
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO userinfo(username, user_password) VALUES(%s, %s)",(username, user_password))
```

More details please refer to [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html)

Comment: Done. Actually, the problem was quite simple. Instead of 'user_password' I should have typed 'password' because that's the variable in which I had fetched my password into. Anyways, Thanks for helping, that MYSQL documentation is a big life saver.